# How to compress and decompress Arrow or Feather file?

Tags: feather, apache-arrow

I plan to change data file format from parquet to feather. Parquet has compression options(lz4, etc) and I have used them. But I can not find them in feather or Arrow file. Is compression not supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Arrow file format, which is designed for **memory-resident-data, does not support compression algorithms** such as lz4, snappy, gzip, and zlib. The only compression currently supported by Arrow is dictionary compression, a scheme that usually does not require decompression before data processing.

Comment: Note that compression support for on-wire data and Feather files is in the project roadmap, but it has not been implemented yet. We also plan to support some kinds of encodings in-memory in addition to dictionary encoding, such as run-length encoding.

Comment: Feather has compression now as of April 2020 https://ursalabs.org/blog/2020-feather-v2/